# Cannot access Kibana remotely

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, kibana

**my kibana.yml:**

```
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"
```

ufw deactivated - *only for testing*

iptables deactivated - *only for testing*

**PORT 5601**

```
tcp   0  0 0.0.0.0:5601  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  1757/node
```

when i try to access kibana local it gives me:

```
* Connected to domain.com (my ip) port 5601 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: domain.com:5601
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< kbn-name: kibana
< kbn-version: 5.2.2
< cache-control: no-cache
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 217
< accept-ranges: bytes
< Date: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 12:28:06 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<script>var hashRoute = '/app/kibana';
var defaultRoute = '/app/kibana';

var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash.length) {
  window.location = hashRoute + hash;
} else {
  window.location = defaultRoute;
* Connection #0 to host domain.com left intact
}</script>
```

still cant access kibana via domain.com:5601 in my browser also ip_adress:5601 not working

Comment: Could this be a cloud instance that blocks most ports by default? That configuration would be in the UI or API of the cloud provider

Comment: no :( its a root server from a hoster in my town. And the Service Team told me that they didn't block any ports at all.